# Adobe Edge workin?

Tags: flash, adobe-edge

Does the new Adobe Edge product truly enable Flash based websites and games to be wrapped and sold into the iTunes store? Our company is always looking to get into the iPad but, until now is not convinced that any product out there will give us the interactivity that Flash gives us for our virtual science labs. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

No, Adobe Edge is a motion/animation tool. It doesn't have much to do with Flash at all.

Perhaps you are thinking of Adobe AIR, which does allow you to make Flash programs including games into desktop and mobile apps. [Adobe AIR does work on iOS](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air_for_ios.html).